# TextInput inside Text component lose focus after each input (IOS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create a filling blank for a paragraph with React Native
[Render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmO5P.png)

However, whenever I input a character, the keyboard automatically close.

I'm using React Native 0.63.3

Below is my code for App.js:

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'


export default function App() {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 44 }}>
      <Text>
        <View style={{ height: 20, width: 100, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }} >
          <TextInput value={txt} onChangeText={setTxt} />
        </View>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ullamcorper volutpat velit id mollis. Nulla bibendum congue malesuada. Phasellus scelerisque est quis lacinia porta. Etiam sit amet vehicula nisl. Sed porttitor vestibulum tellus, ac convallis quam pulvinar sit amet. Suspendisse ac consequat ante. Duis cursus, leo a hendrerit efficitur, libero nisi tristique erat, cursus venenatis est tellus eget nisi. Etiam dictum, tellus sed ultrices mattis, lectus quam convallis sem, cursus maximus turpis nisl id nulla. Vestibulum pharetra erat at velit tempor, vitae interdum turpis blandit.
         </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I wonder if there is something wrong in my code or is there a different approach with View instead of Text that can produce the same result?

Update: whenever I tried with more than one TextInput in Text component, one of them will crash the application (debugging shows error "Attempt to get layout metrics from dirtied Yoga node")

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'


export default function App() {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 44, flex: 1 }}>
      <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'black',
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={txt}
            onChangeText={setTxt}
          />
        </View>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ullamcorper
      volutpat velit id mollis. Nulla bibendum congue malesuada. Phasellus
      scelerisque est quis lacinia porta. Etiam sit amet vehicula nisl. Sed
      porttitor vestibulum tellus, ac convallis quam pulvinar sit amet.
      Suspendisse ac consequat ante. Duis cursus, leo a hendrerit efficitur,
      libero nisi tristique erat, cursus venenatis est tellus eget nisi. Etiam
      dictum, tellus sed ultrices mattis, lectus quam convallis sem, cursus
      maximus turpis nisl id nulla. Vestibulum pharetra erat at velit tempor,
      vitae interdum turpis blandit uhm.
      <View
          style={{
            height: 20,
            width: 100,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'black',
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={txt}
            onChangeText={setTxt}
          />
        </View>
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add flex: 1 in styles of your text tag. If this is your main screen than you should also add flex: 1 to the top most view

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 44, flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
      style={{
        height: 20,
        width: 100,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
      }}
    >
      <TextInput
        style={{ zIndex: 999 }}
        value={txt}
        onChangeText={setTxt}
      />
    </View>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ullamcorper
    volutpat velit id mollis. Nulla bibendum congue malesuada. Phasellus
    scelerisque est quis lacinia porta. Etiam sit amet vehicula nisl. Sed
    porttitor vestibulum tellus, ac convallis quam pulvinar sit amet.
    Suspendisse ac consequat ante. Duis cursus, leo a hendrerit efficitur,
    libero nisi tristique erat, cursus venenatis est tellus eget nisi. Etiam
    dictum, tellus sed ultrices mattis, lectus quam convallis sem, cursus
    maximus turpis nisl id nulla. Vestibulum pharetra erat at velit tempor,
    vitae interdum turpis blandit.
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I have tried using the code above directly on App.js but the issue is still there.